# Filter a list based on elements in that list

Tags: clojure

I have lists similar to this :

```
'(
    ; element 1
    (
        ((X hello))
    )

    ; element 2
    (
        ((X hello)(Y world))
        ((X hello) (Y earth))
        ((X hi) (Y planet))
    )

    ; element 3
    (
        ((Y world))
    )        
)
```

I'd like to make a loop or something that can give me an "intersection" of the elements in that list. For exemple for the list above the result should be something like that :

```
((X hello) (Y world))
```

Indeed this result is the only one that can satisfy the X and Y. I'm very new to clojure so if you also have advices for a better data structure, they're also welcome.

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on your definition of 'intersection'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-think the problem a bit. Right now, an intersection would produce the null set.

In addition, you may wish to study the built-in functions like

- https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/set
- https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.set/intersection
- [The Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html)